Shouldn't we wait a bit longer before closing questions?
Why I ask was triggered by this question, but I have witnessed the same pattern often enough, so now the proverbial barrel is full and overflowing.
Basically, Wyatt certainly knows the other question and its answers, being a very curious user who isn't content with superficial answers. Or needs to be helped along every step of the way. I see evidence for both. Closing the new question and referring him to older answers he has all read will not be helpful to him. If the new question helps to gain a new angle and interpret the old answers better, why not let him have his ways? Maybe more people will have the same question?
I don't mind careful purging, but maybe we should wait until some more time has passed for the new question to collect more votes and answers and we can see better if it is worthy to be kept. Half a day certainly isn't enough.

The quicker closing of questions is one of the effects of only requiring 3 votes (as opposed to 5 votes before). If there are many community members who share your concern, we may want to reconsider the move to 3 votes is out.

@PeterKämpf: I voted to close the question you are talking about and I still think that it is a duplicate of the older one. Plus the answer you gave to the old one is much better and definitely more comprehensive than the new one

If a question should be closed, it should be closed as soon as possible. If it should be open, it can be reopened, and as soon as possible.
An insistence on keeping questions open when they are not up to standard only ever invites half-baked answers that must be updated in response to the question's own shifting, or which must scattergun to explain everything instead of addressing a precise exact query.
An insistence on not using the system as it is designed and intended and set up to function, will never achieve a more useful result, than just using the system properly.
Entirely separately, if the existing answers are not good enough, the correct approach is bounties seeking new answers or comments requesting clarification. "I want my own special version of the question with my own answers" is just not good enough for Stack Exchange.
